# How to set Data Display Key to from JSON API a variably

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to make a HTML form that shows data from JSON APIs.But I need to set the data-display key to a variable , because I will use two dependent drop lists and I have to log the selected from the first list and use it's value as the data display key of the second one.

html:

```
<form>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="client">Select payment</label>
      <select 
      class="form-control" 
      name="payment" 
      id="payment" 
      data-source="https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/ptnaed3a6a4nr" 
      data-displayKey="Client_Name">
      </select>
    </form>
```

JS :

```
 $('select[data-source]').each(function select() {
  var $select = $(this);

  $select.append('<option></option>');

  $.ajax({
    url: $select.attr('data-source'),
  }).then(function select(options) {
    options.map(function select(option) {
      var $option = $('<option>');

      $option
        .text(option[$select.attr('data-displayKey')]);

      $select.append($option);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Your data source isn't even giving anything besides some `{N#A:N#A}`

Comment: I think it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I See you using JQuery you can use

```
$.getJSON( "url", function( data ) {
    var items = [];
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
         items.push( "<option value='" + key + "'>" + val + "</option >" );
    });
    $( "<selector>", {
       "class": "my-new-list",
        html: items.join( "" )
        }).appendTo( "selector" );
     });
```

for more info check this url [1](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)